# Is it possible to separate Admin and Users table in MVC .Net

Tags: .net, authentication, model-view-controller, membership

So far I have seen that for both kinds of users, i.e, website user and admin user, there's a single table provided by MVC, i.e., UserProfile. But I have a question is that really a good practice. For example, if your site has thousands of users, then the login process might take a bit of a time and when you are the admin, you want results fast, you want to be able to log in faster. Forgive me if it sounds stupid.

Also, does this not expose a single point of compromise? if someone gets hold of the table data, then they have all your data, both Users info and Admin info. Sure the passwords are hashed and difficult to crack but still is this a good practice?

With that said, is there a way to create additional table for admin and still utilize the .Net way of processing login as for UserProfile table? In short can I make two separate tables and utilize the same functionality?

Comment: If login consists primarily of looking up and validating a single row, then a proper index should provide all the speed you are likely to need. Many applications require finer distinctions, e.g. Admin, WebAdmin, Editor, Client, DesignatedVictim, ... . Using a separate table for each becomes problematic. And a single user may have more than a single role.

Comment: Thanks @HABO. Just needed this extra confirmation. I think I'll keep the same tables just separate the UI.